# Usb switch - concurrent use of docking station hdd for 2 Windows based PCs

Tags: usb, switch

I am looking for a usb switch to connect two Windows based pc's to a single usb docking station...what i have found so far are products with a switch for exclusive connection of one pc or the other...
Is there a usb switch allowing concurrent, simultaneous use...?

I know that there is strong possibility for data corruption...
I know it's a poor man's and lame as it gets solution but
the client does not want a network based solution or sharing of any sort and wants to spend pennies...

Thank you!

Comment: Two Windows computers to connect locally will have a Router.  Use traditional folder sharing to share documents. Fairly easy to do and almost for sure cheaper than a likely pricey two computer USB Dock.

Comment: As i mentioned the client doesn't want a network based solution, i.e intermediate switch or router or even crossover cable...All network based solutions, even SCP, SFTP, budget NAS integration where presented...and rejected...

Comment: If computers have internet (I don’t see any without) then the hardware is already there. I did read your post but doing things the hard way is indeed strange.

Comment: Indeed strange...what can i say...no internet allowed by the way on the 2 machines...Air-gapped machine of some sort...

Comment: Give up, stop wasting time.  What you're looking for simply does not exist because it can't work.  USB is a master-slave topology.  A slave cannot serve two masters.